# Where to insert overflow:x?

Tags: html, css

I have a grey background rectangle upon which I've to position elements with position: relative, the rectangle should go out of the page and I'd have to ue overflow-x: hidden, but the problem is that when I use it it messes up all the page. Where should I place overflow-x without messing up all the page? Should I change the HTML?

I tried to place it in main or to wrap the div inside another div use the wrapper for overflow-x, but it still messes up all the page!

```css
body {margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 16px;}

.under-bg_blue-big {float: right;
                height: 690px;
                width: 690px;
                background-image: url(../img/bg-intro-desktop.svg);}

.list {position: relative;
   float: right;
   color: white;
   z-index: 5;
   margin-top: 36px;
   margin-right: 0px;
   padding-left: 0px;}

nav > ul > li {list-style: none;
           display: inline;
           position: relative;
           z-index: 5;}

.under-bg_white-btn {margin-right: 16px;
                 font-size: 12px;}

.under-bg_green-btn {background-color: #06d89b;
                 padding: 8px 21px;
                 border-radius: 5px;
                 margin-right: 24px;
                 font-size: 12px;}


.logo {float: left;
   width: 180px;
   margin-top: 4.58%;
   margin-left: 8.19%;
   position: relative;
   z-index: 1;
   margin-bottom: 170px;
   clear: both;}

.block-hero {text-align: center;}

.block-hero__hero {float: right;
               position: relative;
               top: 190px;
               right: -50px;}

.section-a {padding-top: 284px;
        margin-left: 8.19%;}

.section-a__heading {width: 34.375%;
                 font-size: 40px;}

.section-a__par {width: 35.28%;}

.section-a__btn {padding: 27px 90px;
             background-color: #06d79d;
             border: none;
             border-radius: 5px;
             color: white;}

.under-bg_grey {background-color: #fafafa;
            height: 744px;
            width: 150%;
            margin-top: 30%;
            position: relative;
            left: -50px;
            clip-path: inset(0% 0% 0% 0% round 100px);
            font-size: 14px;
            z-index: 0;
            transform: rotate(15.589deg);
            clear: both;}
```

```html
<main>
  <section class="section-a">
    <h1 class="section-a__heading">All your files in one secure location, accessible anywhere.</h1>
    <p class="section-a__par">Fylo stores all your most important files in one secure location. Access them wherever you need, share and collaborate with friends, family and co-workers.</p>
    <button type="button" name="button" class="section-a__btn">Get 
    Started</button>
  </section>
  <div class="under-bg_grey"></div>
</main>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow! Did you tried to put it on the body? That is usually the best place to put it if you don't want any scroll-x on your page.

Comment: you should change width:100% instead of 150% for .under-bg_grey class

Comment: @Trisma I tried bt it doesn't work! No, the rectangle should not be 100%, but it has to overflow and I've to cut it.

Comment: I don't quite understand the ultimate intent here. What are you trying to accomplish with that `overflow-x:hidden;` exactly?  Do you mean to cut off the content of the grey background area?  Fit the content elements within it with that large curve that it has?  Please clarify  it messes up all the page" what does that mean in your mind here?

Comment: I just want to cut off the grey box that goes off the page, now it works with both html and body {overflowx: hidden}. With only one of those nothing happens. If I use overflow-x: hidden on a wrapper or main  it changes the layout of the page, that what I meant for "it messes up all the page".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this code..

**css**

```
main{
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
.under-bg_grey {
  background-color: #fafafa;
  height: 744px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 30%;
  position: relative;
  left: -50px;
  clip-path: inset(0% 0% 0% 0% round 100px);
  font-size: 14px;
  z-index: 0;
  transform: rotate(15.589deg);
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: It messes up the page too!

Comment: try to add body{overflow-x:hidden;}

Comment: i think there is no body div in html

Comment: There is the body div

Answer (score 1):

If you want the div with the class 'under-bg_grey' as a background for other elements you can change the styles for the particular element as follows.

```
.under-bg_grey {
    background-color: #fafafa;
    height: 744px;
    width: 150%;
    margin-top: -25%;
    position: relative;
    left: -50px;
    clip-path: inset(0% 0% 0% 0% round 100px);
    font-size: 14px;
    z-index: -1;
    transform: rotate(15.589deg);
    clear: both;
}
```

Think so there would not be any need for overflow-x property.

I hope the above provides what you needed :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding `overflow-x: hidden` to the `main` element should do the trick.

As in:

```
main {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Here's the working demo:

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

main {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.under-bg_blue-big {
  float: right;
  height: 690px;
  width: 690px;
  background-image: url(../img/bg-intro-desktop.svg);
}

.list {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  color: white;
  z-index: 5;
  margin-top: 36px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

nav>ul>li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
}

.under-bg_white-btn {
  margin-right: 16px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.under-bg_green-btn {
  background-color: #06d89b;
  padding: 8px 21px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-right: 24px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
  width: 180px;
  margin-top: 4.58%;
  margin-left: 8.19%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-bottom: 170px;
  clear: both;
}

.block-hero {
  text-align: center;
}

.block-hero__hero {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: 190px;
  right: -50px;
}

.section-a {
  padding-top: 284px;
  margin-left: 8.19%;
}

.section-a__heading {
  width: 34.375%;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.section-a__par {
  width: 35.28%;
}

.section-a__btn {
  padding: 27px 90px;
  background-color: #06d79d;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
}

.under-bg_grey {
  background-color: #fafafa;
  height: 744px;
  width: 150%;
  margin-top: 30%;
  position: relative;
  left: -50px;
  clip-path: inset(0% 0% 0% 0% round 100px);
  font-size: 14px;
  z-index: 0;
  transform: rotate(15.589deg);
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section class="section-a">
    <h1 class="section-a__heading">All your files in one secure location, accessible anywhere.</h1>
    <p class="section-a__par">Fylo stores all your most important files in one secure location. Access them wherever you need, share and collaborate with friends, family and co-workers.</p>
    <button type="button" name="button" class="section-a__btn">Get 
    Started</button>
  </section>
  <div class="under-bg_grey"></div>
</main>
```

Comment: There must be other important CSS on your page you haven't included in the snippet above. Can you share the full CSS and HTML for the page?

Comment: Added the new css file, can you please check it?

Comment: When you say 'it messes up all the page', what do you mean?

Comment: If I add it to the body it has no effect, if I add overflow.x on the section-a class or main  it changes the layout of the page

Comment: Are you adding `overflow-x: hidden;` to the `main` element?

Comment: Yes, I  tried but doesn't work. It works if I use overflow-c on html element. But don't know why.

Comment: Is there more to your HTML than you're showing? The demo above works, which probably means your local code is different from what I have in the example above.

Comment: Yes there is more, but I solved using both overflow-x on html and body, if I use only on one it doesn't work! Do you want more html?

Comment: Nope, sounds like you already solved it. The additional HTML was probably the culprit. Remember in the future to share all the necessary code to reproduce the issue, that way we can help you more quickly.

Comment: Ok, I’ll try..I wanted to keep the things short..Still don’t understand why it takes 2 overflow-x: hidden instead of only one..Isn’t it repetition?

Answer (score 0):

take one div with class name name grey_box and next put your div which has class name under-bg_grey inside it. Take .grey_box div width 100% and overflow-x:hidden. I think this code will help you,

```
    <style>
       .grey_box{
        width:100%;
        overflow-x:hidden;
        }

    </style>

    <body>
      <div class="grey_box">
           <div class="under-bg_grey"></div>  
     </div>
    </body>
```